# Re-use aggregate calculations in different parts of a CASE statement

Tags: google-bigquery, case, aggregate-functions

I have a table `myTable`, with a single column table containing an integer that represents a single byte value like this:

```
status_code
-----------
(single bit values:)
1
2
4
8
(multiple bit values:)
...
12
3
etc.
```

I'm selecting an overall 'status' based on the total proportion of bits that match a certain value, using logic that looks like the following. As you can see, there's a bit of repetition where I'm re-performing some identical calculations:

```sql
select 
       (case when (sum(case when status_code >> 4 = 1 then 1 else 0 end) / count(*)) + 
                  (sum(case when status_code >> 3 = 1 then 1 else 0 end) / count(*)) > 0.75
             then 0
       else 
          case when (sum(case when status_code >> 4 = 1 then 1 else 0 end) / count(*)) + 
                    (sum(case when status_code >> 3 = 1 then 1 else 0 end) / count(*)) +
                    (sum(case when status_code >> 2 = 1 then 1 else 0 end) / count(*)) > 0.75
               then 1
          else 
               case when (sum(case when status_code >> 4 = 1 then 1 else 0 end) / count(*)) + 
                         (sum(case when status_code >> 3 = 1 then 1 else 0 end) / count(*)) +
                         (sum(case when status_code >> 2 = 1 then 1 else 0 end) / count(*)) +
                         (sum(case when status_code >> 1 = 1 then 1 else 0 end) / count(*)) > 0.75
                    then 2
               else 
                 3
               end
          end
        end) as status 
from myTable
```

How can I simplify the query (and probably make it more performant), by re-using the calculated proportions of each individual status? For example, how could I maybe alias the following and re-use it in different parts of the case statement?

```sql
(sum(case when status_code >> 4 = 1 then 1 else 0 end) / count(*))
```

Is that even possible?

Comment: Are you aware of bigquery bit function? https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/bit_functions

Comment: Thanks @Tamier Klein. That counts the number of bits represented in each byte, whereas I'm counting the proportions that have been set for each bit, across all records

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I simplify the query?

Below is one of the option, I think

```sql
#standardSQL
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION f(code INT64, bits INT64) AS (
  IF(code >> bits = 1, 1, 0)
);
SELECT (CASE 
  WHEN (SUM(f(status_code, 4)) + 
    SUM(f(status_code, 3))) / COUNT(*) > 0.75 THEN 0
  WHEN (SUM(f(status_code, 4))  + 
    SUM(f(status_code, 3))  +
    SUM(f(status_code, 2))) / COUNT(*) > 0.75 THEN 1
  WHEN (SUM(f(status_code, 4)) + 
    SUM(f(status_code, 3)) +
    SUM(f(status_code, 2)) +
    SUM(f(status_code, 1))) / COUNT(*) > 0.75 THEN 2
  ELSE 3
  END) AS status 
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

or further "refactoring" gives:

```sql
#standardSQL
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION f(code INT64, bits INT64) AS (
  IF(code >> bits = 1, 1, 0)
);
SELECT 
  (CASE 
    WHEN SUM(f(status_code, 4) + f(status_code, 3)) / COUNT(*) > 0.75 THEN 0
    WHEN SUM(f(status_code, 4) + f(status_code, 3) + f(status_code, 2)) / COUNT(*) > 0.75 THEN 1
    WHEN SUM(f(status_code, 4) + f(status_code, 3) + f(status_code, 2) + f(status_code, 1)) / COUNT(*) > 0.75 THEN 2
    ELSE 3
  END) AS status 
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

> and **probably** make it more performant ...

So, finally

```sql
#standardSQL
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION f(code INT64, bits INT64) AS (
  IF(code >> bits = 1, 1, 0)
);
SELECT 
  (CASE 
    WHEN f4 + f3 > 0.75 THEN 0
    WHEN f4 + f3 + f2 > 0.75 THEN 1
    WHEN f4 + f3 + f2 + f1 > 0.75 THEN 2
    ELSE 3
  END) AS status 
FROM (
  SELECT 
    SUM(f(status_code, 4))/ COUNT(*) f4, 
    SUM(f(status_code, 3))/ COUNT(*) f3, 
    SUM(f(status_code, 2))/ COUNT(*) f2, 
    SUM(f(status_code, 1))/ COUNT(*) f1 
  FROM `project.dataset.table`
)
```